# Eager load single item with Eloquent belongsToMany

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a Batch model, which hasMany Results and belongsTo a Project. The current status of a batch is based on the status of its most recent Result. So, in my batch model I have this:

```
public function allForProject($pid)
{
    $batches = $this
        ->with(static::$relatedObjects)
        ->with('current_status')
        ->where('project_id', '=', $pid)
        ->get();
    return $batches;
}

public function current_status()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('BehatEditor\Models\Result')
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->limit(1)
        ;
}
```

...So by saying "->with('current_status')" I am trying to eager load only the most recent result for that batch - there may be thousands of them per batch that I do not want to return to the front end.

Now, this doesn't break, but the "limit(1)" actually seems to limit the number of Batches that get returned with a Result. Even though each one of my Batches has 2 results with my test data, when I use limit(1) only one of them comes back with any data. When I use limit(2), only 2 batches come back with a single current_status record (desired) but the rest have an empty array for current_status.

This is a Silex project using Eloquent as an ORM, so Laravel specific methods won't work.

Any help is much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

It looks like Eloquent just doesn't support this. see http://irclogs.julien-c.fr/2013-12-19/01:48#log-52b25061a599aafb54008650.  I would like to update my question to be how can I cleanly add the raw SQL I need to my query? Can I supply my own method that holds only the SQL needed, or do I need to replace all ORM usage in allForProject()?

Comment: Is it really `belongsToMany` or `hasMany` as you say in your 1st paragraph?

Comment: @crypticsymbols is your update still applicable or has this been implemented in Laravel?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `->limit(1)`, use `->first()`.

Update: Misread what you said, this should work.

Comment: Hmm... this throws "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()".